# linq to entities - how to query dates that are stored as char?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-functions

In the db table the dates are stored in a char(8) field in this format yyyyMMdd.
How do I query for a date range?

I tried the following and it does not work:

```
context.Where(p=> Convert.ToDateTime(p.Date) >= Convert.ToDateTime('20120411');
context.Where(p=> Convert.ToInt32(p.Date) >= Convert.ToInt32('20120411');
context.Where(p=> int.Parse(p.Date) >= int.Parse('20120411');
```

From what I've read a possible way is to use EntityFunctions class but I'm not sure how to construct the query.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the test string to a date:

```
context.Where(p=> Convert.ToDateTime(p.Date) >= DateTime.Parse("2012/04/11 00:00:00");
```

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
context.Where(p=> p.Date.CompareTo("20120411") >= 0);
```